# How to detect click in rotated image or rect in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I need to detect click on image/rect in HTML canvas, please check the attached image.
The click is only valid if it is within the green rectangle after rotation. Red rect is the original rect before rotation. I can not use any third-party library, so please give solution which doesn't require any external js or library.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What results did it produce? Can you share some code?

Comment: i'm new in HTML canvas development, so nothing much i have tried with, there were some code i have found but that doesn't work with rotated image and accurate to satisfy the above result.